# yum behind proxy not working : Could not retrieve mirrorlist 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: proxy, centos7, yum

I have a CentOS7 behind a proxy :

```bash
$ grep proxy /etc/yum.conf
proxy=http://10.10.30.90:80/
```

and the http stream to that proxy is allowed :

```bash
$ : < /dev/tcp/10.10.30.90/http
$ echo $?
0
```

I'm trying to use yum behind that proxy by it fails retrieving the mirrorlist :

```bash
# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesnt have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum wont use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

How can I make this work ?

Comment: Have you tried to `curl` this url? Just to check that proxy allow you to pass.